# Solving for the parameters of a discrete markov state model

Tags: markov-process, hidden-markov-model

I have some observations $y_t \in \mathbb{R}_+, t\in 0 \dots n$, and I'd like to fit the following model: a vector of initial states $p_0 \in \mathbb{R}^s_+$, transition probabilities $K \in \mathbb{R}^{s \times s}_+$, and emission probabilities $b \in [0,1]^s$, satisfying:

$$
\min_{p_0, K, b} \sum_{t=0}^n (y_t - p_0^TK^tb)^2
$$

This is similar to an HMM except that every hidden state contributes to the emission, or a Markov Chain/Markov State Model where the states are hidden by the emission probabilities $b$. This feels like it should be easier than estimating the parameters of an HMM, but I've looked at  [MSMBuilder](http://msmbuilder.org/3.8.0/index.html), [hmmlearn](https://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), and [PyEmma](http://www.emma-project.org/latest/), and none of them quite work. The HMM modules can't handle the existence of a distribution over hidden states and the Markov Chain models seem to expect that the states are observed instead of hidden behind emission probabilities.

Comment: I don’t understand your objective function. What do you think the last term is doing, in plain English?

Comment: Basically $p_t \centerdot b = y_t$, where $p_t = p_0K^t$ is the distribution of hidden states of the population at time $t$.

Comment: Okay, I see what confuses me about your model now. You’re using squared error at each observation, and you say that the observations are positive real numbers. But multiplying probabilities together won’t (can’t) get you those. (Are your observations discrete?) I think you’re suggesting an abstract solution to your concrete problem that’s *almost* what you want. If you specify the model, I can work back from there to say how the model should be defined.